# how can i get notified on every control clicked in another application?

Tags: wpf, windows, winforms, hook

Im writing an application that needs to get notified when a control in another application is clicked\invoked. How can i catch the click from my application?

Here are some more related questions :

- Is UIAutomation can be a solution? is it working on unmanaged applications also?
- Is the Spy++ solution works also on managed applications?

i'll be happy with any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `Global Hooks`, but in managed apps you can only set up `Global Hooks` for keyboard and mouse events. So you will need to write an unmanaged app to do this.

Here's a blog post where a MS guy discusses the internals of Spy++ which might be useful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/vcblog/archive/2007/01/16/spy-internals.aspx